# Refresh Combobox in user userform1 with close userform2 - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

I want to refresh **userform1 combobox** values by closing the **userform2** window. (*Without putting the commandbutton  and only with the window closing*)

Comment: Please read [ask], save a minute for the [tour], and see [*Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1188513).

Comment: Hi Mathieu Gindon!
Thank you for your advice. But I did not find a sentence or method easier than what I wrote for my question. What part of the subject is the problem? Need to provide code or send a photo? You have a history of nearly 7 years and have a history of nearly 6 months! Please give me more guidance. @MathieuGuindon

Comment: Well, as is made abundantly clear in the meta-question I linked to, SO isn't a code-writing service: "I need XYZ, how do I do that, here's *nothing*" isn't exactly a *specific* question, no matter how clearly you state your specifications and requirements. So yes, including the code you have (**not** a picture of it) and explaining what's wrong with it, what errors you're getting, what it's doing vs what you're expecting it to do, [...], makes a huge difference between "can someone do XYZ for me" and "I have XY, how do I get to Z".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create 2 UserForms.

On UserForm1 put this code:

```
Dim WithEvents frm2 As UserForm2

Private Sub frm2_Closed()     
   MsgBox "Closed!"
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()  
    Set frm2 = New UserForm2
    frm2.Show
End Sub
```

On Userform2 put the code:

```
Public Event Closed()

Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
RaiseEvent Closed
End Sub
```

You can change the code to do what you want.

When the UserForm2 is closed, an event is raised and UserForm1 handle it.